# How to call Navigation Events from a Stack in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When i navigate away from a screen called GridVid, 2nd in my StackNavigator, i'd like to call a NavigationEvent function onWillBlur().

So in my SettingsClass, 1st screen in the Stack, this works fine, i can call onWillBlur(), because it's in the App.js file.

However trying to call onWillBlur() in the 2nd screen in the stack (called GridVid, defined in the GridVid.js file) doesn't work. How can i solve this?

//App.js

```
class SettingsClass extends Component {

    render() {
          return (
            <View style={styles.settingsContainer}>
               <NavigationEvents
                       onWillBlur={() => {
                           alert('moving from Settings') //THIS WORKS FINE!!!
                       }}
              />
            </View>
            )
          }
   } 


    //Tabs across the bottom of the screen
    const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        HomeScreen: { 
            screen: HomeClass,
        },

        SettingsStack
      },
    )

    //Settings Class swipes to GridVid
    const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
      SettingsScreen: {
        screen: SettingsClass
      },
      GridVid: {
        screen: GridVidClass
      }
   })
```

//GridVid.js

```
export default class GridVidClass extends Component {

  render() {
   return (
    <View style={styles.container}> 
         <Text>On Grid </Text>

         <NavigationEvents
           onWillBlur={() => {
               alert('moving from GridVid')  //THIS DOESN'T WORK...
           }}
      />

    </View> 
    );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Event addListener. It can solve the problem.

Exmaple

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 this.willBlur = props.navigation.addListener(
    'willBlur',
    () => {
       alert('moving from GridVid');
    }
  );
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.willBlur.remove();

  }
```

And, use the `push` command to render the screen.

```js
this.props.navigation.push('Gridvid');
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. I just needed to setState in the willBlur and willFocus, within the constructor. No need to push another screen.